# Is there an algorithm for computing pushouts in $\sf FinSet$?

Tags: algorithms, category-theory

Does anyone know of an algorithm for computing pushouts in $\sf FinSet$, the category of finite sets and mappings?

That is, given finite sets $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with maps (of sets)  $f: X \to Z$ and $g: X \to Y$, is there an algorithm for computing the object $C$ and the maps from $Z$ to $C$ and $Y$ to $C$ which together form the pushout of the original diagram?

Comment: Two issues: 1) Which environment category are you considering (sets with total functions, finite sets with total functions, etc)? 2) If you know how to calculate coproducts and coequalizers then there is a well known method explaining how to calculate pushouts (and indeed all colimits); a good summary of the method is given in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171920/whats-special-about-the-simplex-category/171975#171975

Comment: HSN: Yes! The question should be fixed now.

Comment: Boumol: I mean the category Finite Set, where an object is a finite set and a map is a map of sets. I will read through that construction you sited.

Comment: If you want to notify someone of your comment, you need to use the '@' sign, [cf. here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Anyway, you still haven't explained what you mean by "compute"; surely you don't just want the description $Z \cup_X Y = (Z \sqcup Y) / (f(x) \sim g(x))$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for asking what do I mean by compute. If I asked for a computation for say, the sum (in Finite Set) of two objects,  the description alone is good enough. But in the case of pushouts, I think the description is not the entire story. I think the answer is in boumol's comment: the proof is constructive and can be used to generate an algorithm. What I was hoping for was a very specific discussion of an algorithm for pushouts. A good example which I think indicates why one would want an algorithm to compute pushouts is Exercise 2.6.2.4 from http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6946

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what could be considered an algorithm here, but would the following satisfy you for example? "Take the disjoint union of $Y$ and $Z$. For every element $x \in X$, identify $f(x) \in Y$ with $g(x) \in Z$."

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks for replying. maybe I am wrong, but the relation is the finest equivalence. that makes it tricky to compute. say $x_1 -> z_1$ , $x_1 -> y_1$, $x_2 ->z_1$ and $x_2 -> y_2$. Then we would identify $z_1$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ all together, is that not correct? So the pushout would have 1 element in this case. As the sets get bigger this computation gets trickier. I am looking at database functions trying to find one which is equivalent to the pushout construction. I will let you know what I find. I appreciate your input.